# Present perfect + past simple (sequence of tenses)

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, sequence-of-tenses

I came across these sentences:

- "**I've** found out that you **lied**.
- "**I've discovered** that she **was** untrue to me".

It confuses me, because I thought, that according to the rule "sequence of tenses" we can use **present perfect** with present simple or future simple.

I think that in the first sentence **"found" in Past simple** instead of **present perfect** should be used (or **I've found** out that you **lie**). What about the second one, I think that **I discovered** that she **was** untrue to me/ **I've discovered** that she **is** untrue to me is more suitable.

If I am wrong can you me explain why. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the intended meaning.

*I've found out that you lied* means 'you told a lie on a particular occasion in the past'. Using *lie* would change the meaning to 'you are a habitual liar'.

Similarly with the second sentence. Either she *was* unfaithful on a particular occasion, or she *is* habitually unfaithful.